# dijit.form.DateTextBox - configure width of "day-of-month-box"

Tags: jquery, css, dojo, dijit.form

Theres a dijit.form.DateTextBox which works fine but has an unlucky style.

[image]

The inner box showing the days of the month does not have the same width as the other elements.

The Dropdown does have the right width and should not be changed.
What I need is to get the inner box as wide as the other ones.
Though I would like to ask you where to do that.

The used library is dojo-1.12.2.

The picker is included into jsp by a custom taglib.
The code for this looks like:

```
<a:datetimepicker key="myKey" name="myObject.datumVon" displayFormat="dd.MM.yyyy">
    <s:param name="labelcolspan" value="%{1}" />
    <s:param name="inputcolspan" value="%{1}" />
</a:datetimepicker>
```

The regarding ftl code looks like:

```
<#include "/${parameters.templateDir}/${parameters.theme}/controlheader.ftl" />

<div
<#if parameters.toggleType?if_exists != "">
<#if parameters.toggleType=="time">
 dojoType="dijit.form.TimeTextBox"<#rt/>
</#if>
<#if parameters.toggleType=="date">
 dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox"<#rt/>
</#if>
<#else>
 dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox"<#rt/>
</#if>
></div>

 <#include "/${parameters.templateDir}/qxhtml/controlfooter.ftl" />
```

The resulting CSS viewed on the firefox inspector looks like:

```
<div widgetid="dijit_form_DateTextBox_0_popup" id="dijit_form_DateTextBox_0_popup" style="-moz-user-select: none; top: 0px; visibility: visible;" class="dijitCalendarContainer dijitInline dijitCalendar" role="presentation" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_DateTextBox_0_popup_mddb dijit_form_DateTextBox_0_popup_year" lang="de">
<div class="dijitReset dijitCalendarMonthContainer" role="presentation">
    <div class="dijitReset dijitCalendarArrow dijitCalendarDecrementArrow" data-dojo-attach-point="decrementMonth">
        <img src="/myproject/static/js/dojo-1.12.2/dojo/resources/blank.gif" alt="" class="dijitCalendarIncrementControl dijitCalendarDecrease" role="presentation">
        <span data-dojo-attach-point="decreaseArrowNode" class="dijitA11ySideArrow">-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="dijitReset dijitCalendarArrow dijitCalendarIncrementArrow" data-dojo-attach-point="incrementMonth">
        <img src="/myproject/static/js/dojo-1.12.2/dojo/resources/blank.gif" alt="" class="dijitCalendarIncrementControl dijitCalendarIncrease" role="presentation">
        <span data-dojo-attach-point="increaseArrowNode" class="dijitA11ySideArrow">+</span>
    </div>
    <span widgetid="dijit_form_DateTextBox_0_popup_mddb" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitDropDownButton" lang="de"><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:__onClick" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode"><span style="-moz-user-select: none;" tabindex="-1" id="dijit_form_DateTextBox_0_popup_mddb" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents dijitDownArrowButton" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode,titleNode,_arrowWrapperNode,_popupStateNode" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_DateTextBox_0_popup_mddb_label"><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitNoIcon" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" id="dijit_form_DateTextBox_0_popup_mddb_label"><div class="dijitSpacer"><div month="0" class="dijitCalendarMonthLabel">Januar</div><div month="1" class="dijitCalendarMonthLabel">Februar</div><div month="2" class="dijitCalendarMonthLabel">März</div><div month="3" class="dijitCalendarMonthLabel">April</div><div month="4" class="dijitCalendarMonthLabel">Mai</div><div month="5" class="dijitCalendarMonthLabel">Juni</div><div month="6" class="dijitCalendarMonthLabel">Juli</div><div month="7" class="dijitCalendarMonthLabel">August</div><div month="8" class="dijitCalendarMonthLabel">September</div><div month="9" class="dijitCalendarMonthLabel">Oktober</div><div month="10" class="dijitCalendarMonthLabel">November</div><div month="11" class="dijitCalendarMonthLabel">Dezember</div></div><div class="dijitCalendarMonthLabel dijitCalendarCurrentMonthLabel">Juli</div></span><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitArrowButtonInner"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitArrowButtonChar">▼</span></span></span><input value="" class="dijitOffScreen" tabindex="-1" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode" aria-hidden="true" type="button"></span>
</div>
<table summary="Juli" role="grid" data-dojo-attach-point="gridNode" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th class="dijitReset dijitCalendarDayLabelTemplate" role="columnheader" scope="col"><span class="dijitCalendarDayLabel">M</span></th><th class="dijitReset dijitCalendarDayLabelTemplate" role="columnheader" scope="col"><span class="dijitCalendarDayLabel">D</span></th><th class="dijitReset dijitCalendarDayLabelTemplate" role="columnheader" scope="col"><span class="dijitCalendarDayLabel">M</span></th><th class="dijitReset dijitCalendarDayLabelTemplate" role="columnheader" scope="col"><span class="dijitCalendarDayLabel">D</span></th><th class="dijitReset dijitCalendarDayLabelTemplate" role="columnheader" scope="col"><span class="dijitCalendarDayLabel">F</span></th><th class="dijitReset dijitCalendarDayLabelTemplate" role="columnheader" scope="col"><span class="dijitCalendarDayLabel">S</span></th><th class="dijitReset dijitCalendarDayLabelTemplate" role="columnheader" scope="col"><span class="dijitCalendarDayLabel">S</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-dojo-attach-point="dateRowsNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick: _onDayClick" class="dijitReset dijitCalendarBodyContainer">
            <tr class="dijitReset dijitCalendarWeekTemplate" role="row"><td aria-label="26. Juni 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarPreviousMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">26</span></td><td aria-label="27. Juni 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarPreviousMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">27</span></td><td aria-label="28. Juni 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarPreviousMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">28</span></td><td aria-label="29. Juni 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarPreviousMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">29</span></td><td aria-label="30. Juni 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarPreviousMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">30</span></td><td aria-label="1. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">1</span></td><td aria-label="2. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">2</span></td></tr><tr class="dijitReset dijitCalendarWeekTemplate" role="row"><td aria-label="3. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">3</span></td><td aria-label="4. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">4</span></td><td aria-label="5. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">5</span></td><td aria-label="6. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">6</span></td><td aria-label="7. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">7</span></td><td aria-label="8. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">8</span></td><td aria-label="9. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">9</span></td></tr><tr class="dijitReset dijitCalendarWeekTemplate" role="row"><td aria-label="10. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">10</span></td><td aria-label="11. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">11</span></td><td aria-label="12. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">12</span></td><td aria-label="13. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">13</span></td><td aria-label="14. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">14</span></td><td aria-label="15. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">15</span></td><td aria-label="16. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">16</span></td></tr><tr class="dijitReset dijitCalendarWeekTemplate" role="row"><td aria-label="17. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">17</span></td><td aria-label="18. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">18</span></td><td aria-label="19. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">19</span></td><td aria-label="20. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">20</span></td><td aria-label="21. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">21</span></td><td aria-label="22. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">22</span></td><td aria-label="23. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">23</span></td></tr><tr class="dijitReset dijitCalendarWeekTemplate" role="row"><td tabindex="0" aria-label="24. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">24</span></td><td aria-label="25. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">25</span></td><td aria-label="26. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">26</span></td><td aria-label="27. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">27</span></td><td aria-label="28. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">28</span></td><td aria-label="29. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">29</span></td><td aria-label="30. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">30</span></td></tr><tr class="dijitReset dijitCalendarWeekTemplate" role="row"><td aria-label="31. Juli 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">31</span></td><td aria-label="1. August 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarNextMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">1</span></td><td aria-label="2. August 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarNextMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">2</span></td><td aria-label="3. August 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarNextMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">3</span></td><td aria-label="4. August 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarNextMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">4</span></td><td aria-label="5. August 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarNextMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">5</span></td><td aria-label="6. August 2017" aria-selected="false" class="dijitCalendarEnabledDate dijitCalendarNextMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" data-dojo-attach-point="dateCells"><span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="dateLabels">6</span></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="dijitReset dijitCalendarYearContainer" role="presentation">
    <div class="dijitCalendarYearLabel">
        <span data-dojo-attach-point="previousYearLabelNode" class="dijitInline dijitCalendarPreviousYear" role="button">2016</span>
        <span data-dojo-attach-point="currentYearLabelNode" class="dijitInline dijitCalendarSelectedYear" role="button" id="dijit_form_DateTextBox_0_popup_year">2017</span>
        <span data-dojo-attach-point="nextYearLabelNode" class="dijitInline dijitCalendarNextYear" role="button">2018</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to change the datepicker in any way as follows (without any effect until now):

add one of the following in ftl-file:

```
dayWidth="200px"<#rt/>
dayWidth="100%"<#rt/>
class="datePickerMyProject"<#rt/>
style="background-color:#ff0000;"<#rt/>
```

where "datePickerMyProject" is then a css in the global css file of the application containing one of the width styles from above.
Even using a bgcolor somewhere did not change the color.

Due to an online search I found several keywords to set the styling with but I do not know how exactly to use them. I just tried to add them into either my global css.class or directly within the jsp containing the picker.

.myField.dijitTextBox.dijitTimeTextBox

.dijitCalendarContainer

.dijitCalendarPopup

Any help would be grateful.
Thanks in advance.